# Android Instant App deep link

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-8.0-oreo, deeplink

I declared the below in feature module.i tested instant app in mobile device it runs successfully.but when I type this url it not lead to instant app.what is procedure to launch instant app from URL. Thanks in advance

```
<data
   android:host="abc.cde.com"
   android:pathPattern="/hello"
   android:scheme="https"/>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html

Comment: Did you publish the app?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by “type this url“? If you’re typing it in browser’s address bar, it’s not supposed to work this way. You can launch a published instant app by opening a URL from apps like Gmail, Hangouts, Google search results, etc (try an existing instant app by launching it via https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty URL). Or you can search for “buzzfeed tasty” in your browser, and you’ll see a “Buzzfeed app - instant" in the search results, this link will launch the Buzzfeed instant app.

Comment: i didnt publish the app. i want to go to instant app when i enter the url in chrome or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Android Instant Apps [code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/hello/features/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L36):

The Activity you want to address needs an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true"
        android:order="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="hello.instantappsample.com" />
    <data android:pathPrefix="/hello" />
</intent-filter>
```

Where host and path should match the URL you want to use as entry point for this Instant App's feature.